# How to send Http Post parameter using x-www-form-urlencoded in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am Beginner in Ionic 2. I want to make user registration from app .For user registration i am using api which METHOD is **POST** and its media type is **x-www-form-urlencoded**. I want to send data into server but i am unable to send request successfully.

Please I need some help.[![enter image description here][1]][1]

In My **POST** request there are **9 parameter**
They are  :

**1.officername**
**2.officename**
**3.designation**
**4.emailed**
**5.landlinecode**
**6.landlinenumber**
**7.mobilenumber**
**8.password**
**9.status**

This is my code

```
 doLogin() {
   let url = "http:////Registration";

  var headers = new Headers()
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

   let body= JSON.stringify({ officme: 'mr',emled:'adminac.com', mobilenumber:'9025225',
    password:'12345',offm:'mrc',desigtion:'prrammer',landlinecode:'0000',
   landlinenumber:'888888',status:'A'});
   alert(body);


  return this.http.post(url, body, options) .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
              data => {
                console.log(data);
              },
              err => {
                console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
              }
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please replace this code i hope it will work as per your requirment

```
doLogin() {
   let url = "http:////Registration";

  var headers = new Headers()
   headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


    let body =  "offiername=" +'mr' + "&emailed=" + 'admin@mac.com' + "&mobilenumber=" + '9025225' + "&password=" + '12345' + "&officename=" + 'mrc' + "&designation=" + 'programmer' +"&landlnecode=" + '0000' +"&landlinenumber=" + '888888' +"&sttus=" + 'A';

    alert(body);

  return this.http.post(url, body, options) .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
              data => {
                console.log(data);
              },
              err => {
                console.log("ERROR!: ", err);
              }
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like below code :

```
 let url = "http://host//Registration";

    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin' , '*');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT');
    headers.append('Accept','application/json');
    headers.append('content-type','application/json');
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers:headers});
   return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{


      let body= JSON.stringify({ officername: 'mrsac',emailed:'admin@mrc.com', mobilenumber:'902160',password:'12345',officename:'mr',designation:'programmer',landlinecode:'0000',
   landlinenumber:'888888',status:'A'});

           this.http.post(url,JSON.stringify(body), options).subscribe(res => {
              resolve(res.json());
            }, (err) => {
              reject(err);
            });

   })
```

Comment: when i am trying this request from postman , i am getting user_id "ex:123" when its successfully register . its working with postman. But when i am trying to post from app its gives me "0"